# How to open the "Find" dialog from Python code on Windows?

Tags: python, windows

I am creating a Python-based app for Windows, and I need to open the "Find" dialog from Python code. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.startfile` `operation` argument for this. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) for more information.

For example, this code will open the "Find" dialog from C:\ drive.

```
import os


os.startfile("C:\\", operation="find")
```